# How can I compare/sort elements of a list container containing a custom typedef?

Tags: c++, list, stl, compare, containers

I want to use the `std::list` STL container to be able to apply an order on the items contained. However, the items I want to use are a custom `typedef` consisting of a custom type and a `double` which represents a weight. How can I make sure that I can sort the resulting list based on the weight of the elements?

```
typedef std::pair<linearVariable*, double> weightedVariable;
```

[...]

```
std::list<weightedVariable> tmp;
```

What do I have to do to make sure that the list is sorted according to the second part of the pair (the weight)? Is there any better way to maintain an order of custom types? In my case the weight is not a property of the `linearVariable`, but it can be calculated.

Comment: "Is there any better way to maintain an order of custom types?" if by "maintain an order", you mean that you're going to add new elements to the container and then sort it again after each one then yes there is a better way: `std::set`. If you're only sorting once then `vector` or `deque` would probably be better than `list` unless you do a lot of remove-from-middle. If you only sort once *and* do a lot of remove-from-middle then it might be close between `list` and `set`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`std::list::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort) with a custom comparison function:

```
inline bool comp(const weightedVariable& lhs, const weightedVariable& rhs)
{
  return lhs.second < rhs.second;
}

tmp.sort(comp);
```

Another option is to provide a `bool operator<` and use `std::list::sort()`:

```
inline bool operator < (const weightedVariable& lhs, const weightedVariable& rhs)
{
  return lhs.second < rhs.second;
}

tmp.sort();
```

Comment: You could probably override the < or > operator instead aswell. Might be worth mentioning, since this might make other things more logic in certain cases.

Answer (score 0):

Since [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11), you can also use a [lambda expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) instead of defining a comparison function or operator:

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    typedef void linearVariable;  // Dummy to make the code compile.
    typedef pair<linearVariable*, double> weightedVariable;
    list<weightedVariable> tmp;

    tmp.emplace_back(make_pair(nullptr, 0.4));
    tmp.emplace_back(make_pair(nullptr, 0.8));
    tmp.emplace_back(make_pair(nullptr, 0.2));

    tmp.sort([](const weightedVariable& a, const weightedVariable& b) {
        return a.second < b.second;
    });

    for (auto const &wv : tmp)
        cout << wv.second << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 0.2
>   0.4
>   0.8

[Code on Ideone](https://ideone.com/whmueo)